# What Type of Goumi is this?

Tags: aquarium, fish

I have 1 goumi and I can't figure out what type he is?
I think that it could be a Red Fire Dwarf Gourami but not sure.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! What research did you do until now? Some basic effort should be done before asking here... Same for the snail question.

Comment: I did lots and I think I do know what this species is but I might need someone to tell me if I am right. I think that it is a Red Fire Dwarf Gourami. As for the snails I did a lot of research as well and I couldn't find any the matched what I have.